# android getting custom contact type label name

Tags: java, android, contacts

I'm having trouble finding out how to query a custom phone number type. Like if you go into contacts-edit contact and change one of the phone numbers to a custom label. Is there a way to get the name entered into the custom type label?
I have tried

> "android.content.res.Resources.getSystem() .getStringArray(
>   android.R.array.phoneTypes)"

but it just seems to crash the app and I think its for an old version of android.
 And I have also tried

> curser.getString(curser.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone
>       .LABEL)".

If anyone has an idea it would be greatly appreciated, or maybe point me to a duplicate if one exist I couldn't find one though.

Answer (score 3):

right now I've been doing the same thing, after ensuring your queries are correct (i'm querying ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI) (make sure your projection's are right, etc.) you can do something like below, i guess the difficulty you're facing is picking up a preset label vs. a custom label. preset labels are represented as integers in the TYPE column whereas if the TYPE == TYPE_CUSTOM, the LABEL field will have the data you're looking for.

moving from numbers in TYPE to a string is with a method provided. i'm not sure about the localization though i think that's handled.

```
Cursor curse = mContext.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL}, 
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " = ?", new String[]{numnum}, null);
                int colIndex = curse.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE);
                int lblIndex = curse.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL);
                ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
                String cur = "";
                while(curse.moveToNext())
                {
                    int labelType = curse.getInt(colIndex);
                    if(labelType == ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_CUSTOM)
                    {
                        cur = curse.getString(lblIndex);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        CharSequence seq = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.getTypeLabel(mContext.getResources(), labelType, "Mobile");
                        cur = seq.toString();
                    }
                    numbers.add(cur);
                }
                curse.close();
```

at the end of this snippet you'll end up with an arraylist of strings filled with the labels used for this phone number. note that the phone number needs to be a pretty precise match, so 444-4444 will not match up with 4444444 and vice versa.

personally, i haven't had time to experiment with what the difference is between putting "Mobile" or "" on the last variable in getTypeLabel though it didn't appear to make a difference just yet.

hope this answer wasn't too late.

Answer (score 1):

In this way, in `typeName` you will get the standard or the custom label. (`crPhones` is the cursor that iterate the numbers associated to a single contact):

```
String label = crPhones.getString(crPhones.
        getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL));
int type = crPhones.getInt(crPhones.
        getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
String typeName = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.
        getTypeLabel(context.getResources(), type, label).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code.

First, get type and label.

and get label using getTypeLabel function.

```
fun getPhoneNumbers(contactId: String): ArrayList<ContactNumber> {
        val result = ArrayList<ContactNumber>()

/*///////////////////////////get type and custom label*/

        val phoneFetchCursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                arrayOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL),
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactId, null, null)


        while (phoneFetchCursor.moveToNext()) {
            val num = phoneFetchCursor.getString(phoneFetchCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER))
            val typ = phoneFetchCursor.getInt(phoneFetchCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE))
            val label = phoneFetchCursor.getString(phoneFetchCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL))


 /*///////////////////////////getTypeLabel's third parameter is custom label. 
when it is null then it returns localized default label.*////////////////////////
            val typName = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.getTypeLabel(context.resources, typ!!, label).toString()

            var contactNumber = ContactNumber(contactId, num, typ,typName)
            result.add(contactNumber)
        }
        phoneFetchCursor.close()

        return result
    }
```